# Purple screen when rendering in Blender

Tags: rendering, texturing, image

I have 3 images as planes and I've meshed them to fit a 3D TV model which is just a basic cube with the faces mapped to images. The images as planes are videos that I have on my local machine.

When I render, one of the videos starts glitching and flickers between a purple screen. When I looked the issue up, the community mentioned it's because Blender may not be able to locate the file or fetch it's resources, but that doesn't make sense because the screen is not permanently purple, it flickers. I also relinked everything and used the Find Missing Data tool to ensure this.

I'm still unsure as to why it's happening and would appreciate any feedback.

[image: Normal]

[image: Glitching]

Comment: I see you're not getting any help here.   I think your question is light on details.  May I suggest making a blend file copy and: 1) first try to simplify the rightmost "screen" down to an image sequence on a plane.  2) If problem persists, then delete all else from the file (other objects and materials), pack resources, use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) to include a link in your question.

Comment: +1 to james_t ... Even I haven't seen this kind of issue the purple is missing image, even video file is accessible there is always chance of some video's codec issue. Exporting video into image sequence and used us animated texture is simple way to identify the issue.